# Polymer 1.0 array splice is deleting the wrong item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, splice, html5-template

I am trying to create a simple to do list in Polymer, and I have the add portion working. When I click the "delete" icon next to the item, it deletes the most recently added item instead of the one that it should delete. It looks like it's getting the wrong index of the array, and I'm not sure how to fix it? Thanks!

```
<dom-module id="my-todo-list">
<template>

<div class="card">

  <div class="form">
    <paper-input label="Task" value="{{todo.task}}"></paper-input>
    <paper-button raised on-tap="_addTodo">Add Todo</paper-button>
  </div>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}">
    <paper-card class="todos">
      <paper-checkbox id="checkTodo" on-click="_completeTodo"></paper-checkbox>
      <p>{{item.task}}</p>
      <iron-icon icon="delete" on-tap="_destroyAction"></iron-icon>
    </paper-card>
  </template>

</div>

</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-todo-list',

  properties: {
    todo: {
      type: Object,
      value: function() {
        return {};
      }
    },
    todos: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        return [];
      }
    }
  },

  _addTodo: function() {
    console.log(this.todo);
    this.push('todos', this.todo);
    // this.todo = {};
  },

  _destroyAction: function(todo) {
    var index = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
    this.splice('todos', index, 1);
  },
});
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: in your _destroyAction() callback, the todo argument is an event object, not the todo object you want to delete.

Comment: How should I write it so that it is the object I want to delete? this.todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you always insert the same reference to the object `this.todo` in your `_addTodo()` method. Instead you should make a copy of the object. You sould also add an ID to  differentiate it from the other items.

```
  _addTodo: function() {
    var copy = Object.assign({}, this.todo);    
    copy.id = this.push('todos', copy);
    // this.todo = {};
  }
```

Then you sould add the same ID in the HTML template:

```
<paper-card class="todos" id="{{item.id}}">
```

Now you can modify the `_destroyAction()` method to find the right element in the array, using `Array.findIndex()` method and `Event.target` property:

```
  _destroyAction: function(ev) {
    var index = this.todos.findIndex( function(item) { 
        return item.id == ev.target.parentElement.id 
    } );
    this.splice('todos', index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.indexOf` does not work for looking up objects. You can use a utility library like lodash or `Array.prototype.find`. It's not supported in all browsers though, so make sure to include a polyfill. Both find in lodash and the native one take a callback function as an argument.